# SQL Server query displaying null instead of 0 using Count and GroupBy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query :

```
select 
     Pr.Name, PS.TotalSales, PS.Truesales
From 
     Product Pr
Left Join 
     (select ProdudtId, TotalSales = COUNT(Transaction.Id),
            Truesales = COUNT(DISTINCT case when .Transaction.ExceptionCode  = ' ' then Transaction.Id END)
     from [Transaction] 
     WHERE   
        (ResponseTime < '2013/05/16 01:53:52' and  RequestTime > '2013/05/11 01:53:52')
     Group By 
          ProductId) PS on PS.ProductId = Pr.ProductId
```

I get a result like this :

```
Name TotalSales  TrueSales
AB     3             2
CD     NULL          NULL
EF     1              1
```

I would like to get a result like this

```
Name TotalSales  TrueSales
AB     3             2
CD     0             0
EF     1              1
```

I would like to see 0's in place of nulls . 
Could anyone tell me what change I need to make in the query?

The two tables are as follows :

```
    1 ) Product 
    ProuctId, Name 

2) Sales
TransactionId, ReqTime, ResTime, ProductId(FK), ExceptionCode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Pr.Name, isnull(PS.TotalSales, 0) TotalSales, isnull(PS.Truesales, 0) Truesales
From Product Pr
Left Join (
select ProdudtId, TotalSales = COUNT(Transaction.Id),
Truesales = COUNT(DISTINCT case when .Transaction.ExceptionCode  = ' ' then Transaction.Id END)
from [Transaction] 
WHERE   
(ResponseTime < '2013/05/16 01:53:52' and  RequestTime > '2013/05/11 01:53:52')
Group By ProductId) PS on PS.ProviderId = Pr.ProviderId
```

Comment: +1 Great ! This works ! I spent so much time on something so simple lik e this.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
select Pr.Name, PS.TotalSales, PS.Truesales
```

to

```
select Pr.Name, IsNull(PS.TotalSales, 0) AS TotalSales, IsNull(PS.Truesales, 0) AS Truesales
```